# C# Input string Error

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax

I'm trying too get the users value entered and count down in seconds from it, but whenever I input anything and click the start button it says input string not in correct format. I've googled and googled and cannot figure out how to get the users input and parse or convert it into an int and countdown from it, whilst updating the label via timer of course.
I'm use to console applications still wrapping my head around the syntax...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Countdown { 

    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 

        int seconds; string user; int test = 30;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tmrCountdown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblDisplay.Text = test.ToString();

            if (test > 1)
            {
                lblDisplay.Text = test.ToString() + " Seconds Remaining";
            }
            else if (test == 1)
            {
                lblDisplay.Text = test.ToString() + " Second Remaining";
            }
            else
            {

                tmrCountdown.Stop();
            }
            test--;
        }

        public void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int test = int.Parse(txtBoxInput.Text);

            tmrCountdown.Start();
        }

        private void txtBoxInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Error is at "int test = int.Parse(txtBoxInput.Text);"

Comment: Before any thing now numbers work (though it doesn't count down from that number) but of course letters/symbols error it out. Is there a more correct method to do this, I'm trying to learn good practices I try to code anything even something simple once a day to improve my learning speed

Comment: `int` also has  a `TryParse` method, you might want to look into that. Right now you are simply assuming the input can be converted to an integer, which is of course not always the case. If `int.TryParse` returns false, display an error message to the user instead of creating an uncaught exception as you do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Parse` into `TryParse` and see what value can't be parsed:

```
public void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(txtBoxInput.Text, out test)) 
      // We succeed in parsing, so we continue with the timer
      tmrCountdown.Start();
    else {
      // We failed in parsing

      // Let's put keyboard focus on the problem text box...
      if (txtBoxInput.CanFocus)
        txtBoxInput.Focus();

      // ... and report what's been happened
      MessageBox.Show($"'{txtBoxInput.Text}' is not a valid integer value", 
                      Application.ProductName, 
                      MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                      MessageBoxIcon.Warning);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both of you, I forgot how and how much checking is needed, now I need to fix my timer loop currently no matter what numbers I input it stays at 0 maybe due to int test = 0; hmm

Comment: @Liam Vallance: quite right, you should use `test` field, not the local variable (I've dropped `int test = 0;`)

Comment: Thought so, works fine now. Thank you to all of you for putting up with a noob, especially with all the questions I've asked. I do keep everything I've learned in a snippet program to help me in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

The first one is the fact that you don't protect your code from invalid inputs. If you don't type something in the txtBoxInput or if you type text that cannot be converted to an integer you get the Invalid String Format Exception

The second problem is the variable *test*. You declare it locally inside the button click and given the fact that you don't get compilation errors then you are not setting the global class level variable with the same name that you are using in the timer Tick event.

So, use TryParse everytime you need to handle user inputs. This will not raise an exception in case of problems, but just return true or false. Finally do not re-declare the *int test* variable inside the button click, but use the global class level variable directly in the output of TryParse

```
public void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Try to convert the input in an integer. If this succeed you have
    // the global variable _test_ set to converted text
    if(!Int32.TryParse(txtBoxInput.Text, out test)
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input. Please type a number!");
    else
        tmrCountdown.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code at your button

```
int test=Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxInput.Text);
tmrCountdown.Interval = test*1000; //have to multiply to 1000 since timer interval value is in milliseconds.
tmrCountdown.Start();
```

Just put integers in your textbox